# MySqlConnection.Open() Error in xamarin.android

Tags: mysql, database, xamarin.android

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOZ8HNJMXXg to try to access database. My Code is exactly the same I have add the needed references(`System.Data;` , `MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`), but I get a `System.TypeInitializationException` when I call the `Open()` function.

Here is my code just in case:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server = db4free.net; Port = 3306; Database = XXX; User Id = XXX; Password=XXX; charset=utf8");

            if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
                msg.Text = "Opened successfully";  //just a textview
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the code that you provided, but I also have the same issue at my side, so I suggest you don't connect your app to  database directly.

You can use web services instead, the web services will handle the interaction between your client and server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget?tabs=windows